# 'Some' how to check its usage as a Determiner or as adjective of number

Tags: adjectives, determiners, numbers, adjective-order

It is said that 'some' classifies as an adjective of number and it is also used as a determiner.
1- When 'some' is used as an adjective in a sentence, how do we check whether it's being used as an adjective or a Determiner? Is it that adjective of number can be considered to be a category of determiner?
2- While defining order of adjectives when more than one adjective is used before a noun, where would 'some' fit in  the order of adjectives before a noun? e.g some aromatic coffee beans- is this example right? If yes, then what 'some' indicates here? determiner or adjective of number?

Comment: As a simple native speaker, I don't know about 'determiner' or 'adjective of number'!  But I can tell you that 'some aromatic coffee beans' is right and refers to a quantity of aromatic coffee beans. 'aromatic some coffee beans' makes no sense.

Comment: Such 'rules' are not used by native speakers, and they are more like 'generalisations' anyway. The sentence "some aromatic coffee beans" you give is clear to a native speaker because *some aromatic* makes no sense. But "more aromatic coffee beans" is ambiguous. When spoken, the meaning could be determined from the intonation, but when written is it *more aromatic*, or *more beans*? Either way, the construction is grammatical, yet needs to be rephrased for clarity.

Comment: It's never an adjective. You're conflating word category (part of speech) and function. In an example like "They invited some friends over", it belongs to the category **determinative** and its function is **determiner**. But in, for example, "They had invited some thirty guests" ("approximately"), it's an **adverb** functioning as a **modifier**.